# Len $a_n$ be infinite sequence such that $|{a_{n+1}}|<|a_n|$. Assumbe that $S_{2^n}$ is bounded. Does it imply that $S_n$ is bounded too?

Tags: calculus, summation

Len $a_n$ be infinite sequence such that $|{a_{n+1}}|<|a_n|$ and let $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n{a_i}$. Assumbe that $S_{2^n}$ is bounded, i.e. there exists positive $B$ such that for any natural $n$ we have $|S_{2^n}|<B$. Does it imply that $S_n$ is bounded too?

Comment: See [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: @Eclipse Sun This series is not positive and I do not ask about convergence.

Comment: The method is nearly the same.